# Wordpress - how disable plugin update check?

Tags: wordpress

I am using "wp-meta-tags" plugin, but every time when I update it, it crashes the web site.
How can I disable the update check in plugin files directly.

Comment: See this plugin will help you : [Disable Specific Plugin Update](https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-specific-plugin-updates/)

Comment: I do not want to use any plugin for this. As I wrote i need to disable it manually  and from plugin files only.

Comment: I see , check this if it can help you  : http://www.thecreativedev.com/disable-updates-for-specific-plugin-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your themes function.php

```
//filter for blocking specific plugin updates
add_filter( 'http_request_args', 'wp_prevent_plugin_update_check', 10, 2 );

function wp_prevent_plugin_update_check( $r, $url )
{
    $parse_url =  parse_url( $url );
    $host      = isset( $parse_url['host'] ) ? $parse_url['host'] : '';
    $path      = isset( $parse_url['path'] ) ? $parse_url['path'] : '';

    if ( $host == 'api.wordpress.org' && $path == '/plugins/update-check/1.1/' )
    {
        $plugins = json_decode($r['body']['plugins'], true);
        $update_blocked_plugins  = array('plugin_folder/plugin_main_file.php');

        foreach ($update_blocked_plugins as $update_blocked_plugin)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($update_blocked_plugin, $plugins['plugins']))
            {
                unset($plugins['plugins'][$update_blocked_plugin]);
            }
        }

        $r['body']['plugins'] = json_encode( $plugins );
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Change `plugin_folder` to your **plugin folder name** and `plugin_main_file.php` to **plugins main php file**

If you want to add more plugins, just add to the `$update_blocked_plugins` array.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple but effective solution is to open your plugin file and change the version number to something very high, this way the plugin thinks it is up-to-date.